# Maintain InDesign CS5.5 Import settings w/ XMPie

Tags: adobe-indesign, xmp

We are trying to use XMPie to dynamically bring in pdf files and center them within a frame. However, in a manner similar to Photoshop the files are being imported by Bounding box and not allowing us to set any other parameters. We can get it to work on an individual level by importing the file but InDesign nor XMPie will remember these settings. Any help would be appreciated.

We need these to import by Media Box and center & we are using InDesign CS5.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to delete everything outside of the visible pdf page size and then place it. I use step and repeat to the same page size by quite imposing in acrobat.